# Use Databricks job to output Hadoop HFile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, databricks, azure-databricks

I to use a Databricks job to use the `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` interface to write an HFile.

Inside a local spark test instance it works great, but inside a Databricks job it fails with:
`NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile`.

## In details

My current dependencies look like that:
[image]

My test notebook has the following steps:

### 1. Some imports

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import java.nio.ByteBuffer

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{Admin, ConnectionFactory, HTable}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, KeyValue, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2

import java.util.UUID

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
```

### 2. Setup hbase config (copied from HBase cluster)

```
val hbaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create()

hbaseConfig.set("dfs.domain.socket.path", "/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket")
hbaseConfig.set("dfs.support.append", "false")
[...]
hbaseConfig.set("zookeeper.session.timeout", "120000")
hbaseConfig.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure")

hbaseConfig.set("hbase.mapreduce.hfileoutputformat.table.name", "DeviceData")
```

### 3. Save DataSet

```
mappedData.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
  stagingDir,
  classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
  classOf[KeyValue],
  classOf[HFileOutputFormat2],
  hbaseConfig
)
```

## The error

```
Caused by: Job aborted due to stage failure.
Caused by: Task failed while writing rows
Caused by: NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1077)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1075)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:994)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:985)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:6)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:90)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:92)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:94)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:96)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:98)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:100)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:102)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:104)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read.<init>(command-4454301442308183:106)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$.<init>(command-4454301442308183:110)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$.<clinit>(command-4454301442308183)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:570)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:219)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:903)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:856)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:544)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:521)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 38) (10.42.240.4 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:791)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2$1.getNewWriter(HFileOutputFormat2.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2$1.write(HFileOutputFormat2.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2$1.write(HFileOutputFormat2.java:239)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1677)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:138)
    ... 19 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2712)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2902)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1028)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2446)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2429)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2467)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2499)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1077)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1075)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:994)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:985)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:6)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:90)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:92)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:94)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:96)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:98)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:100)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:102)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$$iw.<init>(command-4454301442308183:104)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read.<init>(command-4454301442308183:106)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$.<init>(command-4454301442308183:110)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$read$.<clinit>(command-4454301442308183)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at $line3506744ecc8e4b3a8d207e04b18fbe0595.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:570)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:219)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:903)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:856)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:544)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:521)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:791)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2$1.getNewWriter(HFileOutputFormat2.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2$1.write(HFileOutputFormat2.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2$1.write(HFileOutputFormat2.java:239)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1677)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:791)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

## The question

I tried everything to understand whats the difference between the Databricks job and my local one.
I'm absolut out of ideas.

---

### Update 1 - 2021-08-09

We have no also reduced the installed libs to the minimum needed, to use the default installed Hadoop-Common lib and avoid conflicts.

[image: installed libs]

Still getting this neasty error even on really basic static operations.

[image: error]

### Update 2

Based on the [compatibility matrix of HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop), it would be good to know with Hadoop version DataBricks cluster is using by default and how to replace them with a compatible one.

[image]

Comment: I've never used Databricks say first but, `NoClassDefFoundError` is most like that your dependencies is not include in you final package which commit to Databricks. And most like a package step fail.

Comment: what databricks runtime is used?

Comment: the real problem is `Could not initialize class`, I suspect that it's incompatibility between HBase & Hadoop versions

Comment: @AlexOtt its "8.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12)"

Comment: In local development we are using Hadoop 2.7.4, which is the same as used in the Databricks runtime 8.3 to my knowledge. We use HBase 2.4.4 in both cases.

Comment: @AlexOtt for me it fells like the DataBricks cluster is init by default with some older HBase/Hadoop libs that making problems with our installed ones.

Comment: Yes, most probably. I see Hadoop 3.3.1 in your list. I think that you need to remove most of these dependencies, leave only necessary ones - their dependencies should be fetched automatically

Comment: @AlexOtt please see my update in the initial post above. We removed unneeded dependencies but still have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem were some missing dependencies.
The point that I was not able to detect this was, that after cluster restart the concrete error was only showed one time. After this point, any operation on the running cluster only showing the misleading error `NoClassDefFoundError`. I think this is because at cluster start, HBase libraries are doing some initial stuff. If this fails, it will not produce any useful error message until you restart the cluster.

The concrete error here were two missing libraries `org.apache.hbase:hbase-metrics` and `‎org.apache.hbase:hbase-metrics-api`.